# Flutter Align both texts at the start Vertically in a row

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a little stumped here but i'm trying to align two text widgets at the vertical start in a row in Flutter but no matter what I try to do the text is centred in the text widget with less text. I'm trying to get the 'Address' title and the actual address to both start at the top vertically in the row but because the actual address is longer it always centres the Address title (in below image address is centred in the first job in the list).

[image]

This is the code that I am using:

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Status: ', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Text(job['status'])

                  ],),
                  Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Engineer: ', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Flexible(child: Text(job['eng']))

                  ],),
                  Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Address: ', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Flexible(child: Text(job['address']))

                  ],)
                ],)
```

I've tried to mainaxisalignment.start on the row but its not working...any ideas anyone?

Comment: Are you trying to align it horizontally or vertically?

Comment: vertically, I totally messed that up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` on your `Row`

Comment: realised i was making a mistake with some code and this was the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understand what exactly do you want to do but maybe you want to use `Column` instead of `Row` for Address with `crossAxisAlignment`

```
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Address: ',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Text(job['address'])
        ],
      )
```

or maybe

```
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: 'Address: ',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '23 Test Street, Test City',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```